# How do we use rowUpdateBuilder in cassandra to write to an audit table containing a composite partition key?

Tags: java, triggers, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I saw various examples online where cassandra triggers were used to write to an audit table. I was following this one :
https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.0/examples/triggers/src/org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.java

However in my use case, I have an audit table that has a composite partition key ( PRIMARY KEY ((col1,col2),col3,col4) ) and multiple clustering columns.
 I have been able to add the clustering columns by adding audit.clustering(values) but I am not able to figure out how to implement the composite partition key.
RowUpdateBuilder gives me an error if I pass update.partitionKey.partition () as the 3rd parameter of rowUpdateBuilder.

The error is :
Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of components, expecting 2 but got 1.

I get the same error when I pass an array of size 2 as the 3rd parameter to rowUpdateBuilder.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Build composite partition key from all of your partition key**

To build composite partition key from one or more partition key, use the following method :

```
public DecoratedKey buildCompositePartitionKey(CFMetaData metadata, Object... partitionKey) {
    return metadata.decorateKey(
            CFMetaData.serializePartitionKey(
                    metadata.getKeyValidatorAsClusteringComparator().make(partitionKey)
            )
    );
}
```

Example :

```
CFMetaData metadata = Schema.instance.getCFMetaData("test_ks", "test_cf");
DecoratedKey compositePartitionKey = buildCompositePartitionKey(metadata, "col1 value", "col2 value");
RowUpdateBuilder audit = new RowUpdateBuilder(metadata, FBUtilities.timestampMicros(), compositePartitionKey);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly!